# aws cli rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot giving internal error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

Trying to restore a cluster snapshot as part of a code build pipeline to copy a prod db into staging on a regular basis.  Run into an issue with the aws cli command to restore the cluster throwing a strange error below.

Here's the command i'm trying to run below.  It's taken from this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/enhancing-automated-database-continuous-integration-with-aws-codebuild-and-amazon-rds-database-snapshot/

```
aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot \
--snapshot-identifier arn:aws:rds:region-ID:account-ID:cluster-snapshot:db-snapshot-identifier \
--db-cluster-identifier myidentifiernameforrestore \
--engine aurora
```

I get the following error when executing the command:

```
An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot operation (reached max retries: 4): An internal error has occurred. Please try your query again at a later time.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use default engine version? If not, you also must provide `--engine-version`.

Comment: think I'm just using the default

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the last part of the command
`--engine aurora`

Change this to `--engine aurora-mysql` and works and deploys the cluster.

Thanks for the tip @Marcin